# ASP Net Web Api HttpPost losing request

Tags: c#, asp.net, http-post, asp.net-web-api2

I've recently changed from httpget to httppost so I can put a valid json string into the body of my request.  Now when I send the request either running the api locally or by publishing to my local IIS everything works as I'd expect it to.  However, as soon as I deploy to our development web server the "request" gets lost and hits the line of code, return BadRequest("Request is missing");.

Here is the code from my controller,

```
[RoutePrefix("MyPrefix")]
public class InsightController : ApiController
{
    [Route("Load"), AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST"), HttpPost, ResponseType(typeof(Logic))]
    public IHttpActionResult Load([FromBody]MasterRequest request)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return BadRequest(ModelState);

            if (request.IsNull())
            {
                return BadRequest("Request is missing");
            }
...
```

The WebApiConfig code looks like this,

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
        config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*"));
        config.Services.Insert(typeof(ModelBinderProvider), 0, new SimpleModelBinderProvider(typeof(MasterRequest), new RequestModelBinder()));
        config.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
        config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented;
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
    }
...
```

Web.Config,

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
...
```

Header content-type is set correctly to application/json and called with raw json via postman.

Can anyone point out what I've missed?

Thanks.

JSON...
{"Max_Request_Item_Count":0,"CompanyId":999999,"NoOfMonths":12,"RequestedMonth":226,"MileageBaseId":1,"SectorId":null,"ErrorSmoothing":false,"ShowDiagnostics":false,"Identifier":null,"IdentifierId":0,"ConsumerCode":"WEB","SelectedFilterType":0,"ManufacturerIds":[5,3],"RangeIds":[],"FuelIds":[],"EngineIds":[1.6,1.9],"TransmissionIds":[],"DriveIds":[],"BodyIds":[],"PowerIds":[],"WeightIds":[],"DoorIds":[],"VersionIds":[],"CO2Ids":[],"PriceIds":[],"TrimIds":[],"SeatIds":[5],"SectorIds":[],"DateAddedIds":[200,226],"DateOffProduction":"2017-08-01T14:25:09.575305+01:00","IncludeOldModels":true,"IncludedText":"no text","ExcludedText":"no text","Extrapolate":false,"Variables":{},"ElementTypeId":3,"ElementSubTypeId":8,"Created":"2017-08-11T14:25:09.5683034+01:00","CreatedBy":"BURT","CountryId":10,"VehicleTypeId":0,"ManufacturerId":0}

Comment: Json response in postman,

400 Bad Request

{
    "message": "Request is missing"
}

Comment: Can you show the construct of the request before the post is called.

Comment: Hi Bilpor,
Unfortunately I can't due to data sensitivity.  All I can say is that the json string is valid because I used site [link](http://json.parser.online.fr/).

Comment: POST /api/MyPrefix/load HTTP/1.1
Host: dev.com
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: fb584bf8-53ea-a2c4-b13b-5bcba1dade98

Comment: json string is too big to post here so I've added to the bottom of the original question above.

Comment: Do you get the error locally if you make the call via postman to? or does it work locally with Postman? Do other POST's work or do you get similar issues with other POST's

Comment: Works perfectly when I run it up locally or publish to my local iis

Comment: Ok, my initial thought was that it might be CQRS since it works slightly differently under the hood between POST and GET, but if other POSTs are working on your deployed server then this is ruled out

Comment: I see what you were thinking but I'd already configured cors in the webapiconfig

Comment: does the post work and not the get or visa versa or neither. Typically I wouldn't mix the Accept Verbs with the http.Post, since I'd probably be using [FromBody] with the post and [FromUri] with Get. (though this still doesn't explain why it works locally). It might be worth separating them for now t try and isolate which one it is (post or get).

Comment: Initially I was using HttpGetet and sending information via the uri which worked great, but the custom object started to get a little more involved and complex so I had to change it to a post.
With ref to removing Get in the accept verb, it fails and doesn't even get into the controller.  Which makes me think it may be a web server configuration issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the web server (load balanced) was redirecting my post as a get (hence the reason the request was null).  Changed the url to be https and it worked.

@Bilpor Thanks for help.